# Not able to auto read Sms In OREO

Tags: android, sms

In my application, I am auto Verifying the OTP. Its working fine till Nougat.
Then in Oreo , it asks for run time permission for sms but permission is not granted. But if I go in app settings, and then give the permission, then sms is auto read.

Is it the problem with oreo or there is some  fault in my code.

Comment: Yes.. I am showing from there

Comment: Yes.. i waited for  minute.. then also it didn't detect the otp automatically

Comment: Yes, I waited for this

Comment: can you tell me , which is that API

Comment: In this link, there is no as such specification for oreo

Comment: Can you tell me , which part of this code suggests, that will work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes After OREO update You can not read SMS by READ_SMS permission.

Don't worry,

You can replace :

> READ_SMS permission with RECEIVE_SMS

Now Oreo as well as other version also be able to read the SMS.

Comment: but are u able to upload app on play store with this permission